# Счетчик изменений переменной

Tags: java, android

Есть переменная `int plusLength`, которая может принимать различные значения в 3, а позже в 5 методах. И мне нужно реализовать счетчик `count_simbol_up`, который считает сколько раз эта переменная приняла значения больше 3.

Изначально думал, что это просто, но либо я туплю, либо это проще, чем я думаю. В итоге запутался.

Попытка 1:

```
protected  ArrayList<String> buffer = new ArrayList<>();
counterUp(plusLength);

protected void counterUp(int income){
        if (income >2) {
            for(int i=0; i<2; i++) {
                Buffer.add("" + income);
            }
        }
        Log.d("test_-po", "размер: " + (Buffer.size()));
    }
```

---

Попытка 2:

```
int count_simbol_up;
   
counterUp(plusLength);
        
protected void counterUo(int income){
   if (income >2) {
      count_simbol_up++;
       }
  Log.d("test_-po", "размер: " + (count_simbol_up));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static int _count = 0;

private void _add_plusLenght (int _input) {
   if (_input > 3) {
      _count++;
   }
   _plusLenght = _input;
}
```

в теле функций

```
 _add_plusLenght(10);
```

Comment: и... не работает

Comment: Ну а самому отладить? Код простейший. Используй логи

Comment: Я дурак дважды. Когда понял свой ошибку не столько здесь, но и почему все вместе не работало, стало так стыдно, что даже писать такое не буду. Спасибо.

Comment: Это нормально ))